# Service not receiving messages after Message Queuing service restarted

Tags: c#, msmq

We have a service that receives messages from n message queues. However, if the Message Queuing service is restarted, the message retrieval service stops receiving messages even after the Message Queuing service has restarted successfully.

I have tried to specifically catch the MessageQueueException that is thrown in the message retrieval service and invoke the queue's BeginReceive method again. However, in the 2 seconds or so that it takes the Message Queuing service to restart, I get about 1875 instances of the exception and then the service stops functioning when another MessageQueueException is thrown in our StartListening method.

Is there an elegant way to recover from a Message Queuing service restart?

```
    private void OnReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageQueue queue = (MessageQueue)sender;

        try
        {
            Message message = queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);

            this.StartListening(queue);

            if (this.MessageReceived != null)
                this.MessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(message));
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException)
        {
            LogUtility.LogError(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, StringResource.LogMessage_QueueManager_MessageQueueException, queue.MachineName, queue.QueueName, queue.Path));
            this.StartListening(queue);
        }            
    }

    public void StartListening(MessageQueue queue)
    {
        queue.BeginReceive();
    }
```

I need to deal with the infinite loop issue this causes and clean it up a bit but you get the idea.

When the MessageQueueException occurs, invoke the RecoverQueue method.

```
    private void RecoverQueue(MessageQueue queue)
    {            
        string queuePath      = queue.Path;
        bool   queueRecovered = false;

        while (!queueRecovered)
        {
            try
            {
                this.StopListening(queue);
                queue.Close();
                queue.Dispose();

                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                MessageQueue newQueue = this.CreateQueue(queuePath);

                newQueue.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(this.OnReceiveCompleted);

                this.StartListening(newQueue);

                LogUtility.LogInformation(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Message queue {0} recovered successfully.", newQueue.QueueName));

                queueRecovered = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtility.LogError(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The following error occurred while trying to recover queue: {0} error: {1}", queue.QueueName, ex.Message));                
            }
        }           
    }

    public void StopListening(MessageQueue queue)
    {
        queue.ReceiveCompleted -= new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(this.OnReceiveCompleted);            
    }
```

Comment: Posted the RecoverQueue method code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upon receiving the exception that is the result of the service restarting, you have to release the old `MessageQueue`, i.e. unwiring your `ReceiveCompleted` event, disposing the `MessageQueue`, etc. Then create a new instance of the `MessageQueue` and hook up to the `ReceiveCompleted` event again on the new `MessageQueue` instance.

Alternatively, you can use a polling method that creates a new instance on a certain interval, calls `MessageQueue.Receive(TimeSpan)`, will wait for an incoming message or until the timeout occurs. In which case you handle the message and destroy the `MessageQueue` instance and start the iteration again.

By recreating the `MessageQueue` each time, you ensure a built in recovery. Also, the overhead of creating the `MessageQueue` is minimal due to internal caching of the underlying queue.

Pseudo-code...

```
while (!notDone)// or use a timer or periodic task of some sort...
{
    try
    {
        using (MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath))
        {
            Message message = queue.Receive(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

            // process message
        }
    }
    catch (MessageQueueException ex)
    {
        // handle exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so you're just basically saying: "Use a new queue every time."

Comment: @Bob Horn - Yes. Because the overhead is low due to the internal caching, it makes it easier to handle the issues where the MSMQ service was restarted or otherwise becomes unresponsive.

Comment: @Jim- I declare the queue when the service first starts and then set a handler for OnReceived. I have experienced the same issue. The handler gets triggered, encounters a QueueException when doing an EndReceive and reading the message, but that stops the service from ever receiving future messages. How do I handle this exception when I am not using a timer as you described?