# Check if BeginPeek is still Subscribed

Tags: nservicebus, msmq

I am using BeginPeek() /*no params*/ to subscribe to messages coming in to my private queue. This is being done in a service hosted in NServiceBus host. When NServiceBus encounters transport connection timeout exception (i'm seeing circuit breaker armed logs and timeout exception logs), the peek event subscription seems get lost. When database connectivity becomes stable and new messages come in to my queue, the service is no longer notified.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to address this?

Comment: would it be possible to add more details like which NSB Version you are using as well as a small example? Based on your description it is not clear for me why you need to manually peek the queue?

Comment: The service is monitoring incoming messages to the queue. When new messages arrive to the queue, it is processed and 'Received' (deleted from inbox). The service issues another BeginPeek after receiving the message. I am using NServiceBus 5.2.3 and NServiceBus.Host.exe 6.0. The service attaches to Peek event at Start() method, by issuing a msmq.BeginPeek(). The service looses its subscription to Peek event when I restarted the MSMQ service. This was solved by adding dependency to MSMQ, but there are other things that may cause the service to loose Peek subscription.

Comment: Not sure if I entirely follow your description. Are you saying you have two things listening on the same queue? On is the NServiceBus transport itself and your custom queue processing logic? Is your custom logic loosing the peek subscription or NServiceBus?

Comment: I'm sorry if my description is confusing. Ignore NServiceBus for a moment. My main concern is that my service is subscribed to Peek event of a queue. When I restart MSMQ Service, subscription to Peek event is lost. Other event may cause this peek subscription to end. Is there any way to check if Peek subscription is still valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Service not receiving messages after Message Queuing service restarted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336630/service-not-receiving-messages-after-message-queuing-service-restarted)

Comment: @DanielMarbach, yes, that is more or less the same situation I've been on.