# How to reconnect to MSMQ in C# if the service is down for a period

Tags: c#, msmq

Is it possible to reconnect to MSMQ, after the service was shut down, without restarting my application? If it is then how?

my code is:

```
void tmrDelay_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        tmrDelay.Stop();

        while (isConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ImportFromMSMQ.HasMessages())
                {
                    MSMQ_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Transfering data from MSMQ to ActiveMQ started at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                    while (ImportFromMSMQ.HasMessages())
                    {
                        ImportFromMSMQ.Run();
                        MSMQ_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("Transfering data from MSMQ to ActiveMQ completed at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MSMQ_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format("MSMQ is empty {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(string.Format(" Error in data transfer MSMQ to ActiveMQ {0}", ex.Message));
                MSMQ_ServiceLog.WriteEntry(string.Format(" Error in data transfer MSMQ to ActiveMQ {0}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error, -1);
            }
        }

        tmrDelay.Start();
    }
```

The while loop is something that I have added, but not yet tested, because of suspected infinite loop. If one shuts down the MSMQ service we end up in the `catch` clause and we need to restart our whole application when MSMQ is started again. But how can I retry to connect to the MSMQ and keep doing it while waiting for it to be started again?

```
public class ImportFromMSMQ
    {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ImportFromMSMQ));
        //Max records per records
        private static int _maxMessagesPerTransaction = ConstantHelper.MaxMessagesPerTransaction;
        private static bool _isNotCompleted = true;
        private static  int counter = 0;
        private static MessageQueue mq;
        private static long _maxMessageBodySizeLimitInBytes =  ConstantHelper.MaxMessageBodySizeLimitInBytes;

    // Start import 
    public static void Run()
    {
        Start();
    }

    public static bool HasMessages()
    {
        var _mqName = ConstantHelper.SourceQueue;
        mq = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(_mqName);
        long _totalmsg = MessagesCounter.GetMessageCount(mq);

        if (_totalmsg > 0)
        {
            logger.Info(string.Format(" {0} messages found in the {1} Queue ", _totalmsg.ToString(), _mqName));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Info(string.Format(" There are no messages in the {1} Queue ", _totalmsg.ToString(), _mqName));
        }

        return _totalmsg > 0; 
    }


    private static void Start()
    { 

        logger.Info(string.Format("Data transfer starting at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        long _currentMessageBodySizeLimitInBytes = 0;
        ArrayList messageList = new ArrayList();
        System.Messaging.Message mes;
        System.IO.Stream bodyStream = null;
        // Create a transaction.
        MessageQueueTransaction trans = new MessageQueueTransaction();
        List<ConventionalData> objectList = new List<ConventionalData>();
        IMessageContainer _container = new MessageContainer();
        // Begin the transaction.
        trans.Begin();
        try
        {
            while (_isNotCompleted && counter < _maxMessagesPerTransaction)
            {
                try
                {
                    counter++;
                    mes = mq.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3), trans);
                    if (mes != null)
                    {
                        bodyStream = mes.BodyStream;
                        _currentMessageBodySizeLimitInBytes = _currentMessageBodySizeLimitInBytes + bodyStream.Length;
                    }

                   VisionAir.Messaging.ConventionalData data = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<ConventionalData>(mes.BodyStream);
                   objectList.Add(data);

                   _isNotCompleted = _currentMessageBodySizeLimitInBytes <= _maxMessageBodySizeLimitInBytes;
                }
                catch
                {
                    _isNotCompleted = false;
                }
            }

            if (objectList.Count != 0) 
            {
                logger.Info(string.Format("Starting transfer of {0} messages", objectList.Count));
                _container.MQMessages = objectList;
                 ExportToActiveMQ _export = new ExportToActiveMQ(_container, (ExportOption) Enum.Parse(typeof(ExportOption),ConstantHelper.ExportFormat));
                _export.Export();
            }

            logger.Info(string.Format("Transfer of {0} messages is completed at {1}",objectList.Count, DateTime.Now.ToString()));

            // Commit transaction            
            trans.Commit();

            counter = 0; //ResetF
            _isNotCompleted = true; //Reset
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
            // Roll back the transaction.
            trans.Abort();
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at this question [Service not receiving messages after Message Queuing service restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336630/service-not-receiving-messages-after-message-queuing-service-restarted) but do not seem to fully understand it, so if anyone could elaborate on it, it would be nice.

Do I have to recursively call my `tmrDelay_Elapsed()` method I the `catch` clause or something else?

Comment: Basically the guy says that, you don't need to reuse your `private static MessageQueue mq`; instead just create a new one every time because it's easy to handle that scenario

Comment: Okay, so I just have to create an "infinite loop", make an exiting paramater if needed. Then for each message a read I create a new MessageQueue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was simple when I first realized that the first time we access the queue is in the `HasMessages()` method, so I changed it to the following:

```
public static bool HasMessages()
        {
            var _mqName = ConstantHelper.SourceQueue;
            long _totalmsg = 0;
            int countAttempts = 0;

        queueExists = false;
        while (!queueExists)
        {
            if (MessageQueue.Exists(_mqName))
            {
                queueExists = true;

                mq = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(_mqName);
                _totalmsg = MessagesCounter.GetMessageCount(mq);

                if (_totalmsg > 0)
                {
                    logger.Info(string.Format(" {0} messages found in the {1} Queue ", _totalmsg.ToString(), _mqName));
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info(string.Format(" There are no messages in the {1} Queue ", _totalmsg.ToString(), _mqName));
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                logger.Info(string.Format("No Queue named {0} found, trying again.", _mqName));
                countAttempts++;
                if(countAttempts % 10 == 0)
                {
                    logger.Info(string.Format("Still no queue found, have you checked Services that Message Queuing(Micrsoft Message Queue aka. MSMQ) is up and running"));
                } 
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }

        return _totalmsg > 0; 
    }
```

I check if the `MessageQueue.Exists` and keep trying it if it does not exist untill i find the queue. When I find it I set the queueExists to true, to break the while loop to move on and process the data received, if any data is received. I have read in some post that it is bad to use `Thread.Sleep(n)`, but for now I am going with this solution.